# App to open other apps and that act like a viewer

Tags: java, android

I'm a not a very experienced android developer and I would like to ask a question. Is it posible to develop features in android, to make the user able to split the screen and duplicate it (sbs) to be able to see any app in a side by side way with their google cardboard? 
I mean without root the phone. 
Or an app that act like a viewer of other apps, of course has to be able to open other apps, and duplicate the view to watch them in SBS? 
Is this app/feature posible to develop in a normal way without to root the phone?

This is an example for what I want to do:

http://hwahba.com/ibex/

Many thanks

Comment: What kind of Google "glasses" are you referring to? Google Glass or Cardboard?

Answer (score 2):

Actual mulitasking like something like this: http://developer.android.com/preview/features/multi-window.html is not possible as far as I know **yet**.

You could inflate the same layout runtime (with code) in the top relative and change the weightsum to 2 like this:

```
LinearLayout item = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.top_layer_id);
item.setWeightSum(2);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.double_view_thing, null);
item.addView(child);
```

You could also move your view you want to duplicate to a seperate resource and include it two times like this:

```
<include layout="@layout/double_view_thing"/>
<include layout="@layout/double_view_thing"/>
```

Comment: No, that is not what I mean. This is multitasking. What I want is to duplicate the same view of one app, to be able to see the same view twice.

Comment: Aahh, that is perfectly possible. I think you could use layoutinflation for that

Comment: I've edited to add a link were you can see an example but let's say I want to develop an app (A) that does nothing except opens another app (B) and display it twice, split the screen and this way you can see the app B with VR glasses even if the app doesn't natively support it